# how to create nested arrays using the following json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, frontend

I want to create nested arrays using the following json data, but there is a mistake and I couldn't fix it. I've created a sample with jsfiddle. Here is my js sample and code below;

http://jsfiddle.net/r63oxcsk/

The result I want to achieve is as follows;

*Name:

Don

Joan

Surname:

Draper

Harris

Campbell*

```
var Message = [
{
  "OrgID": "11",
  "OrgName": "Name:",
  "orgComboInfo": [
    {
      "OrgID": "11_8",
      "OrgName": "Don",
    },
    {
      "OrgID": "11_15",
      "OrgName": "Joan",
    }
  ]
},
{
  "OrgID": "12",
  "OrgName": "Surname:",
  "orgComboInfo": [
    {
      "OrgID": "12_2699",
      "OrgName": "Draper",
      "OrgType": "12"
    },
    {
      "OrgID": "12_2703",
      "OrgName": "Harris",
    },
    {
      "OrgID": "12_2666",
      "OrgName": "Campbell",
    }
   ]
 }
]

$( document ).ready(function() {
 var arrayB = [];
 var arrayA = [];

 for (var i=0; i<Message.length; i++) {
     var name = Message[i].OrgName;
     arrayA.push(name);

        for (var j=0; j < Message[i].orgComboInfo.length; j++) {
           var surname = Message[i].orgComboInfo[j].OrgName;
                arrayB.push(surname);
        }

        var total = arrayA.concat(arrayB);
        console.log(total);
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the top level array into an object where the property name is OrgName that is an array mapped to the OrgName from the orgComboInfo array.

Reduce starts with an empty object {} and each iteration it spreads the results from the last iteration with a new property named with the OrgName that is the orgComboInfo array mapped to just theOrgName.

```js
var Message = [
{
  "OrgID": "11",
  "OrgName": "Name:",
  "orgComboInfo": [
    {
      "OrgID": "11_8",
      "OrgName": "Don",
    },
    {
      "OrgID": "11_15",
      "OrgName": "Joan",
    }
  ]
},
{
  "OrgID": "12",
  "OrgName": "Surname:",
  "orgComboInfo": [
    {
      "OrgID": "12_2699",
      "OrgName": "Draper",
      "OrgType": "12"
    },
    {
      "OrgID": "12_2703",
      "OrgName": "Harris",
    },
    {
      "OrgID": "12_2666",
      "OrgName": "Campbell",
    }
   ]
 }
]

console.log(
    Message.reduce((result, item) => ({...result, [item.OrgName]: item.orgComboInfo.map(i => i.OrgName) }), {})
);
```

Comment: I have edited the answer to use reduce to be in the shape you want